# Change Skin of Richfaces Application without reloading the page

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2, jboss6.x

I have a JSF 2.2 and Richfaces 4 Application and in that application i have à h:selectonemeun where i have an a4j:ajax with event: on change and listner et status attribute. i want when i change a value of that selectonemenu change the them or the skin of my page whitout reloading all the page (ajax).

```
 <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{managController.selectedProdGroup}"
                        class="validate[required] text-input"
                        requiredMessage="#{messages['group.product.required']}"
                        style=" width : 285px;"
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">

                        <f:selectItem
                            itemLabel="#{messages['productgroup.noselection']}"
                            itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{bManager.productGroupList}"
                            var="productGroupVar" itemLabel="#{productGroupVar.label}" />

                        <a4j:ajax status="loading" execute="@this"
                            listener="#{managController.getProductListByProductGroup()}"
                            onbegin="#{managController.getProductListByProductGroup()}"
                            render="matTable,productList,mForm"
                            event="change" />

                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: i made ...converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" onchange="this.form.submit()"> and that change the page but it work so i will do it with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload you page with:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```